# Bucle for in y addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy intentando mediante un bucle for in hacer que cuando pongo el ratón encima de cada imagen se ponga en color y se agrande y que cuando quito el ratón vuelva a su estado inicial.
El caso es que me funciona pero me sale un error que no me deja continuar haciendo mas javascript y no se porque puede ser. Funciona pero no me deja continuar haciendo más cosas en Javascript porque la ejecución se detiene ahí.
Muchas gracias y buen finde semana a tod@s.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

JAVASCRIPT

```
let eventos = document.querySelectorAll(".evento");
            
            

            for (let evento in eventos) {

                let colorImagen = document.querySelectorAll(".imagen-evento");
                let eventoEnlace = document.querySelectorAll(".eventoEnlace");

                eventos[evento].addEventListener("mouseover", function () { //aquí aparece el error


                    colorImagen[evento].style.filter = "none";
                    colorImagen[evento].style.transform = "scale(1.4)";
                    eventoEnlace[evento].style.bottom = "-100px";


                });

                eventos[evento].addEventListener("mouseout", function () { //aquí aparece el error

                    colorImagen[evento].style.filter = "grayscale(1)";
                    colorImagen[evento].style.transform = "none";
                    eventoEnlace[evento].style.bottom = "0px";
                })


            };
```

HTML5

```
   <h3 class="separador">Eventos</h3>
            <div class="eventos__general ">
                <div class="evento">
                    <img class="imagen-evento" id="img1" src="img/boda-header (2).jpg" alt="evento-deportivo">

                    <div class="eventoEnlace">
                        <a href="#">bodas</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="evento">
                    <img class="imagen-evento" id="img2" src="img/evento-cumpleaños.jpg" alt="evento-cumpleaños">
                    <div class="eventoEnlace">
                        <a href="#">cumpleaños</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="evento">
                    <img class="imagen-evento" id="img5" src="img/evento-privado.jpg" alt="evento-privado">

                    <div class="eventoEnlace">
                        <a href="#">eventos privados</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="evento">
                    <img class="imagen-evento" id="img4" src="img/evento-empresa.jpg" alt="fiesta empresa">

                    <div class="eventoEnlace">
                        <a href="#">fiestas empresas</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="evento">
                    <img class="imagen-evento" id="img3" src="img/evento-deportivo.jpg" alt="evento-deportivo">
                    <div class="eventoEnlace">
                        <a href="#">eventos deportivos</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El bucle [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...in) que has usado itera sobre todas las propiedades iterables del objeto `eventos`, incluidas las heredadas. Si pones un `console.log(evento)` dentro del bucle verás algo similar a esto en la consola:

```
test.html:59 0
test.html:59 1
test.html:59 2
test.html:59 3
test.html:59 4
test.html:59 length
test.html:64 Uncaught TypeError: eventos[evento].addEventListener is not a function
    at test.html:64
```

Cuando llega a la propiedad `length`, como `eventos[evento]` no existe, te da un error.

Lo más sencillo sería que cambiaras el bucle por un bucle [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for) normal, que sirve justo para esto:

```
for (let evento = 0; evento < eventos.length; evento++) {
    [...]
}
```

También puedes asegurarte de que el bucle sólo se ejecutará para las propiedades iterables [propias](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Iterating_over_own_properties_only) del objeto `eventos` y no las heredadas:

```
for (let evento in eventos) {
    if (!eventos.hasOwnProperty(evento)) continue;
    [...resto del bucle...]
}
```

O usar un bucle [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) pero ten en cuenta que en ese caso el valor de `evento` en cada iteración es el propio objeto y no su índice, por lo que tocará cambiar bastante el resto del código:

```
for (let evento of eventos) {
    console.log(evento);
}
```